# Evaluate area of random region covered by disks

Tags: probability-or-statistics, computational-geometry

If I cover a square of side $L$ with $n$ unit disks at random (the disks may overlap the boundary), is there a standard way to evaluate the total covered area $A$?

I am looking to observe the density $f_{A}(x)$.

I am thinking to use implicit region, with the distance to at least one disk centre lesson than 1, but how to you evaluate the area?

[image]

Comment: `r1 = Region[Disk[]]` `RegionMeasure[r1]` gives $\pi$.

Comment: Ok so just apply this to `Region[...]` of a set of random disks?

Comment: Not at all, I am guessing that `RegionUnion` and `RegionIntersection` would also figure prominently in the solution. I was pointing out how to calculate area of an isolated disk region.

Comment: Ok I can see RegionUnion, something like `c = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {2, 2} ]
r1 = RegionUnion[Disk[c[[1]], 1], Disk[c[[2]], 1]];
RegionMeasure[r1]`

Comment: Not Mathematica tip, but check out section "A Generalized Niche Model" in [this article](https://www.pnas.org/content/94/5/1857).

Comment: Highly relevant because it should describe the most performant(?) algorithm known: [Edelsbrunner: The Union of Balls and Its Dual Shape](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02574053).

Comment: With that accuracy you want the answer? Would the share of black pixels on the picture suffice?

Comment: It would suffice, exactness is not crucial at all.

Answer (score 1):

This code will produce a histogram of the random area. It is a bit slow, perhaps someone knows how to speed it up.

```
area[n_] := Module[{c, r1}, c = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {n, 2} ];
  RegionMeasure[
   RegionIntersection[{Rectangle[{-3, -3}, {3, 3}], 
     RegionUnion[Disk[#, 1] & /@ c]}]]]
Histogram[Table[36 - area[10], {i, 1, 100}], {1}];
```

[image]

```
c = RandomReal[{-2, 2}, {10, 2} ];
RegionPlot[RegionIntersection[{Rectangle[{-3, -3}, {3, 3}], 
     RegionUnion[Disk[#, 1] & /@ c]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: You don't take into account the condition" a square of side $ L $".  Your `RegionPlot` differs from the plot in the question. To this end it is enough to take the intersection with a given square in your `Module`.

Comment: Updated, had altered the code for second figure

Comment: Also to demonstrate the "edge" cases, you can have circles closer to the edges and partly outside the rectangular area.

Comment: It should be `RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {n, 2} ]` in your code to satisfy the request in the question.